# SQL 2008 cumulative count

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, cumulative-sum

I have a query returning the number of rows grouped by date :

```
SELECT  convert(date, run.TimeStamp) as TimeStamp, count(*)
FROM  ScriptResult AS res INNER JOIN
    ScriptRun AS run ON run.ScriptRunID = res.ScriptRunID INNER JOIN
    WorkListItems AS wli ON wli.WorkListItemID = res.WorklistItemID INNER JOIN
    WorkList AS wl ON wl.WorkListID = wli.WorkListID
WHERE (wli.WorkListID = @WLID)
GROUP by convert(date, run.TimeStamp)
ORDER BY convert(date, run.TimeStamp);
```

This produces a result set like this :

```
TimeStamp   (ItemCount)
2015-03-10  5364
2015-03-11  22027
2015-03-12  18037
```

Now what I want, is to cumulatively summarize the itemcount, like this :

```
TimeStamp   ItemCount   TotalCount
2015-03-10  5364    5364
2015 -03-11 22027   27391
2015-03-12  18037   45428
```

The query needs to be compatible with 2008R2.
I have played with [count ...over..partition by] in several variations but the problem is that the window function boundary should chage. And I cannot use ROWS or RANGE.

Any ideas please ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with correlated subquery:

```
;WITH cte as(
               SELECT  convert(date, run.TimeStamp) as TimeStamp, count(*) AS S
               FROM  ScriptResult AS res INNER JOIN
                     ScriptRun AS run ON run.ScriptRunID = res.ScriptRunID INNER JOIN
                     WorkListItems AS wli ON wli.WorkListItemID = res.WorklistItemID INNER JOIN
                     WorkList AS wl ON wl.WorkListID = wli.WorkListID
               WHERE (wli.WorkListID = @WLID)
               GROUP by convert(date, run.TimeStamp)
)
SELECT TimeStamp, 
       S, 
       (SELECT SUM(S) FROM cte t2 WHERE t2.TimeStamp <= t1.TimeStamp) AS TS  
FROM cte  t1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try creating a temp table to hold the first query results that you can further aggregate to return the cumulative sum on the ItemCount field:

```
CREATE TABLE #TempTable(
    [SeqNo] [int] NULL,
    [TimeStamp] [Date] NULL,
    [ItemCount] [int] NULL     
) ON [PRIMARY]

SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY res.ScriptRunID ORDER BY run.TimeStamp) AS SeqNo,
    CONVERT(Date, run.TimeStamp) AS TimeStamp, 
    COUNT(*) AS ItemCount
INTO #TempTable
FROM ScriptResult AS res 
INNER JOIN ScriptRun AS run 
    ON run.ScriptRunID = res.ScriptRunID 
INNER JOIN WorkListItems AS wli 
    ON wli.WorkListItemID = res.WorklistItemID 
INNER JOIN  WorkList AS wl 
    ON wl.WorkListID = wli.WorkListID
WHERE (wli.WorkListID = @WLID)
GROUP BY CONVERT(Date, run.TimeStamp)
ORDER BY CONVERT(Date, run.TimeStamp);

SELECT 
     t1.TimeStamp, 
     t1.ItemCount, 
     SUM(t2.ItemCount) AS TotalCount
FROM #TempTable AS t1
INNER JOIN #TempTable AS t2 
    on t1.SeqNo >= t2.SeqNo 
GROUP BY t1.TimeStamp, t1.ItemCount
ORDER BY t1.TimeStamp
```

**[SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/867134/6)**
Note: This links to a Microsoft SQL Server 2014 database version SQL fiddle which should work with SQL Server 2008 as well.

Comment: Thanks, I will have look